# PyCharm can't connect to interpreter in docker

Tags: django, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I use PyCharm 2016.1.4 on a Mac. I followed the instructions [on this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/docker-compose.html), and I want to connect PyCharm to a Django project which runs in docker via docker-compose.

I added the configuration file and service name but when I press OK I get this error:

[image]

Can you help me solve this problem?